# Azure Function.json file incorrect scriptFile property

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-functions

we have started getting the following error in one of our function apps:

```
Invalid script file name configuration. The 'scriptFile' property is set to a file that does not exist.
```

This is a recent development and we have been refactoring the code and configuration so we have obviously done something wrong. I have searched for the error and I keep finding fixes for typescript or javascript. We have written our functions in C# but not sure if either of those two are involved in producing the file.

**function.json:**

```
{
  "generatedBy": "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions-1.0.29",
  "configurationSource": "attributes",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "queueTrigger",
      "queueName": "%CampaignQueueName%",
      "name": "message"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false,
  "scriptFile": "../bin/CampaignIngestion.Functions.dll",
  "entryPoint": "CampaignIngestion.Functions.CampaignSplitterFunction.Run"
}
```

I have checked the path in one of the function.json files and it seems to be correct as I can find the file through Kudo's powershell console.

[image: Image shown at path location]

I suspect we have broken this with some of the configuration changes but we need help to identify where and how to fix this. Any suggestions as to what is causing this please?

Comment: Could you please have a try with "..\bin\CampaignIngestion.Functions.dll" or "..\\bin\\CampaignIngestion.Functions.dll" ?

Comment: I will manually edit to see if it makes a difference but won't I need to fix the generation of this file? Just tried and it appears I don't have permission to edit the file through Kudo.

Comment: Is it a mismatch between the versions?

"generatedBy": "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions-1.0.29",

TargetFramework = .NET Core 2.2\

FUNCTION_EXTENSION_VERSION = ~2

Comment: If I change the FUNCTION_EXTENSION_VERSION from 2 to 1 the functions do start. I am thinking that 2 is the value I want so how do I make it work with 2 versions.

Comment: Share your code in repo if possible...

Comment: Hi, could you please try to change the "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION" from "~2" to "~2.0.11961-alpha" in the configuration of your function app on azure portal ?

Comment: Ok this is a config issue as when we set Functions_Extension_Version to 1 they start and when we set it to 2 it does not. I have looked at the dlls we have referenced:
Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions 1.0.0
Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 1.0.29

but all projects are set to .NETCore 2.2

We are having to set this manually in Azure for now so my question now is how do I populate this value from our deploy script?

Comment: @HuryShen The functions do start when I use the value you asked me to try. What does that mean? How do I get my deployment to use the right value?
The functions are up but it appears that none of the triggers are working at the moment.

Comment: This appears to have started since we have updated a package that pushed our TargetFramework up from netcoreapp2.1 to netcoreapp2.2

Comment: Hi onesixtyfourth, I'm not sure what your problem is, I just know there were breaking [changes](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/129) in 2.0.12050, so to temporarily avoid impact, we can pin the Function App to the previous version of the runtime by updating the app setting FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION to 2.0.11961-alpha